# escaping issue with quotation while echoing a string

Tags: php, wordpress, escaping, quotation-marks

I have a buggy situation that i can't figure out how to solve: i tried to store in the test db some sequential double quotation marks (`""""""""`). Now, when i print them as `value` of an `input type="text"` field, what i get is:

```
<input type="hidden" """"""""="" value="" name="it">
```

Data in the db are passed through `sanitize_text_field(stripslashes())` ([first one is a wordpress core function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field)) and so does not contain slashes at all. How can i fix this? Am i storing data in a wrong way?

Comment: That documentation makes no note about quotations. Try running it through `htmlspecialchars`.  Also is that a dev console output?  Because in the case of html bugs, the rarely exactly the same as the source.

Comment: This may be of help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114354/17187

Comment: thanks @Nabil Kadimi, `esc_attr()` solved the bug. @Flosculus i now that function doesn't say anything about quotations, it was just to give a complete scenario of how the script was working...